# NWS Weather Module API

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I'm using the NWS Weather module.  The builtin block works great but I want to display the current temperatures from two other nearby cities.  In the readme file they state.

> The block defined by NWS_weather allows simple access to weather
>   forecast data for one point. Developers who would like to retrieve
>   data for multiple points or who wish to retrieve more data (wind
>   speed, wind direction, etc.)  can utilize this module by calling this
>   function:
>
> $forecast=nws_weather_NDFDgen($lat, $lon, array('wdir', 'temp',
>   'maxt', 'mint'), "time-series", "2009-12-08T12:00:00",
>   "2009-12-09T12:00:00");

I'm not a developer and have no idea how to use this. I'm wondering if someone could give me some sample code I could work with. I'm working with the 7.x-1.3 version. Thanks guys.

https://drupal.org/project/nws_weather

Comment: While I did not find an answer to my question using the built in module. I found this post that I can use to pull the current temp from their feed. http://webdesign.vassar.edu/2012/07/dynamic-weather-with-noaa-php-jquery-and-html-templates/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the steps:

1. If you haven't the "PHP filter" module enabled, enable it.
2. Create a custom "Block".
3. Set body content as following:

```
<?php

$forecast = nws_weather_NDFDgenByDay('47.53', '-122.30');

echo theme('nws_weather_forecast', 
          array(
            'dataForecast' => $forecast, 
            'required' => array('Daily Maximum Temperature', 'Daily Minimum Temperature', 'Conditions Icons', ), 
            'display' => array('Conditions Icons', 'Weather Type, Coverage, and Intensity', 'Daily Maximum Temperature', 'Daily Minimum Temperature', )
          )
);

?>
```

Here, `47.53` is lat or latitude and `-122.30` is long or longitude. You can also pass day count to display for specific days. Like:

`$forecast = nws_weather_NDFDgenByDay('47.53', '-122.30', 7);`

This will load updates for 7 days.

Then save the Block. And set the currently created block to any region. See the result in front-end. :)

Comment: Thanks you so much for the help.  In your second example with the 7 days listed I had to adjust it a bit for it to work. I looked in the .module file at what they seemed to expect and adjusted it as so.

`$forecast = nws_weather_NDFDgenByDay('47.53', '-122.30', '', 5, '24 hourly');`